# International payroll transfer is not arriving after 2 weeks and I don't know what to do

Tags: salary, salaried-pay

I work remotely for an international company, they always pay me via international wire and it takes between 1 and 2 days to arrive. The latest payment was sent over a couple of weeks ago, my local bank tells me that the normal processing time has already passed and that the sender should ask for it back, but my bosses just tell me to wait and when I asked me to do I recall they said they would try but haven't done anything yet.

I'm asking them to make an exception and send the wire again while they get their refund, I'm really having a lot of personal issues because of this...my life quality is being affected and the bills to pay are just being impossible to handle. What can I do? In which way can I ask for this so that they understand this is crucial for me?

It's a really small company, and I had never had any issue like this after 2 years.

Comment: If more than 2 weeks passed, didn't you get a new pay check? Did your new pay check make it and you have a gap in pay?

Comment: *What can I do?* Start looking for a new job. You've been given no assurance that this will get fixed and it doesn't sound like you can afford to wait, so don't wait.

Comment: Alos, notify the companies you owe bills to that your paycheck has gotten lost, they may be willing to give you some time to pay.

Answer (score 8):

Explain it to them just like you've explained it to us.  Nobody can expect you to just "take it" without even saying anything and all they can do is refuse and make you wait which is what you're already doing.

This could be a red flag though that the company is actually failing.  You may wish to start looking elsewhere.  You don't have to accept anything just yet, but it can't hurt to start putting your feelers out in case the company is indeed failing.  That way you won't be caught unawares and you'll already be starting to find someplace new.

You could additionally offer to wire the money back if the first transfer eventually goes through, citing your long relationship with them.

After reading it again, I suspect that they are in fact stalling you.  It might be a small company, but business is business and it's easier to ignore someone who's a country away. I think you should be a squeaky wheel and make noise.  The truth will come out one way or the other, but you probably are already beginning to realize that this doesn't bode well for long term stability.

Comment: I agree that it is a **big** red flag.  Wire-transfers do not "get lost."  immediately contact the payroll department of the company and ask them to trace the request.  Quite candidly, it's difficult for me to write this comment because all of the **big red flags** that are waving in my face.  (Full disclosure: I worked for a "dot-bomb" company, back in the heyday, and one day walked up to find a chain on the front door: they hadn't paid their rent in months.)